# Photoshop: how to completely to fill an outline drawn with a brush?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, fill

[image]

I drew an outline and filled the inside of it. But it did't get completely filled: there's a white gap between the stroke and the fill.

How can I implement a full fill without this gap?

***Update: add details screen***

[image]

***Update-2***
Tolerance 255(max) and 32
[image]

I always paint over not fill the seats with a brush, but suddenly there is a faster method.

***Update-3***

Use magic wand  = 64.

Can I do something not so I do not understand why we have different results.

Layer transparent, nothing is locked. Magic Wand Tool click on the center of the circle, then pour Paint Bucket with a  of 32 or 230.

The result is as follows:

[image]

**Somehow, on a transparent background  does not work.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Draw a closed form;
2. Take *'Magic Wand Tool'* and click out of shape;
3. *'Select > Modify > Expand > 1 px'* and repeated depending on the contour; (create action or shortcut)
4. *'Select > Inverse'* (Ctrl+Shift+I)
5. *'Paint Bucket Tool'* click 2 times;

If there is more easy for a transparent background, write.

Thank you!

Comment: Clicking the Paint Bucket tool twice really helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to increase the fill tool's `Tolerance` before using it. You can see the value in the options bar, it's 32 in your screenshot.

Tolerance determines how many colour 'levels' will be caught in the filling. When you use the fill tool, you click a pixel, a white one in your example. Pixels more than `<tolerance>` levels removed from that first pixel will *not* get filled.

Since the stroke you drew with a brush in anti-aliased, it is surrounded by pixels in colours between white and your stroke colour. If your tolerance is too low, those will not be included in the fill and remain their original colour. This shows as an off-white inner ring.

Try to increase your tolerance level to 100 or more to obtain a nice fill without that inner ring.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked tolerance and update top post.

Comment: @0x131313 Weird that it doesn't work. If I try to reproduce, a tolerance around 230 works, and 255 colours my entire layer. Are you sure you haven't locked any transparency or such on the layer?

Comment: Layer transparent, nothing is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure of your selection method. Expanding on Vincent's answer: Using the magic wand with tolerance at 64.

[image]

Produced this:

[image]

Filling with the appropriate colour, produced this.

[image]

Comment: Big thanks for answer! I update top post and I somehow different result.

Comment: I think you're getting different results because you had a transparent layer. Now, like Vincent says, adjust the tolerance of your magic wand to something like 100 and then select the inside of the circle. Then fill. If you're still having trouble, once you have your selection try the Refine Edge button. That should help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've found it works to just select with the magic wand and hit the paint bucket 6 or 7 times at a high tolerance.